# problem after dual booting macbook air

Tags: suspend, macbook

I installed ubuntu on macbook air using these instructions

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Trusty

Now whenever I put my mac on sleep (closing the lid) while using os x, the screen doesn't turn on on wake up. So I have to force it to shut down by holding power key and turn it on again.

What should I do? Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ruturaj

Answer (score 1):

> while using os x ??

There is a bug known to do that in Ubuntu .. you can only set brightness to ether 0 or 100 % after suspend ..

but haven't had any problems with OS X ..

It will be better to ask apple's community or their  tech support if you are having problems with OS X

Comment: I installed ubuntu, it works fine. I am sticking to os x on macbook and ubuntu on another laptop for now.

Comment: thank you for the brightness comment! That fixed it for me. Hitting the brightness up button now shows me video.